# Remapping traffic from one port to another using ATS

Tags: django

I have a django application deployed on port 2501. And I have ATS configured to terminate HTTPS, and act as a reverse proxy to route traffic to 2501; my config looks like so:

```
map https://example.com:443/ http://127.0.0.1:2501/
```

And this works great, whenever you hit https://... you'll terminate https and traffic gets routed to 2501. But if you visit 2501 you can access the site normally as well. Is it possible to make it so that if you visit 2501 it'll route you back to 443? I tried using reverse_map but it's not working for me (maybe I'm misunderstanding what reverse map does?)

```
reverse_map http://example.com:2501/ https://127.0.0.1:443/
```

Here's what my uwsgi.ini looks like:

```
[uwsgi]
uid = 1000
gid = 100
master=false
project=myproject
home=/home/someuser/var/virtualenv/myproject
virtualenv=/home/someuser/var/virtualenv/myproject
module=myproject.project.wsgi:application
wsgi-file=/home/someuser/var/virtualenv/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/org/contrib/myproject/project/wsgi.py
pidfile=/home/someuser/var/virtualenv/myproject/tmp/uwsgi.pid
vacuum=True
max-requests=500
daemonize=/home/someuser/var/virtualenv/myproject/tmp/uwsgi.log
env=DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myproject.project.settings
http=127.0.0.1:2501
```

Comment: Can you have Django refuse any connection from an external IP?

Comment: @cwallenpoole that sounds like a very neat solution actually. is that a config on settings.py?

Comment: Depends on how you are serving up `Django`. `python manage.py runserver` defaults to only listening to local IPs.

Comment: I'm serving it through uwsgi

Comment: http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/WSGIquickstart.html Looks like you can bind to a specific socket/IP combination. How are you configuring  and starting it?

Comment: @cwallenpoole just added what my ini file looks like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran a few tests on my server and it looks like you *should* already be good.

Here's what I tried:

```
$ uwsgi --http :9090 --wsgi-file hello-world.py
# I can see the server from an external request.

$ uwsgi --http-socket :9090 --wsgi-file hello-world.py
# I can see the server from an external request.

$ uwsgi --http 127.0.0.1:9090 --wsgi-file hello-world.py
# I cannot see the server from an external request.

$ uwsgi --http 127.0.0.1:9090 --wsgi-file hello-world.py
# I cannot see the server from an external request.
```

By including `127.0.0.1` in that line for configuration, an external IP *shouldn't* be able to access the application, but Apache or NginX should.

Comment: Ah! It seems like there was a lingering uwsgi process that didn't got killed and I managed to access it when the process was down. It's working now!